# Two pickers for 2 textfield in one view

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

I have 2 text fields. Each has own picker view.When a user clicks on each of them, UIPickerView appears. Everything works. However, when,first, I click on the second text field, picker view for the second text field appears, and first text field takes a result from this picker view, not the second one. Something is not right in my code. I cannot figure out what exactly. Please help...Thanks in advance)

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    if (textField == reminder){
        choosen = reminderString;
        mySheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [mySheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];
        myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects: @"15 minutes",@"20 minutes",@"30 minutes", @"45 minutes",nil];

        CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0,44,0,0);
        UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
        pickerView.delegate =self;
        pickerView.dataSource=self;
        pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
        [mySheet addSubview:pickerView];

        UIToolbar *controlToolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, mySheet.bounds.size.width, 44)];

        [controlToolBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
        [controlToolBar sizeToFit];

        UIBarButtonItem *spaser = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
        UIBarButtonItem *setButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"set" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(DatePickerDoneClick)];
        UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancelRepetition)];

        [controlToolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:spaser, setButton, cancelButton,nil] animated:NO];

        [mySheet addSubview:controlToolBar];
        [mySheet showInView:self.view];
        [mySheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 485)];

        return NO;
    }
    else if(textField == repetition){
        choosen = repetitionString;
        repetitionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [mySheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];

        myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"One-time task",@"Daily",@"Weekly",@"Yearly",nil];

        CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0,44,0,0);
        UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
        pickerView.delegate =self;
        pickerView.dataSource=self;
        pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
        [mySheet addSubview:pickerView];


        UIToolbar *controlToolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, mySheet.bounds.size.width, 44)];

        [controlToolBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
        [controlToolBar sizeToFit];

        UIBarButtonItem *spaser = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
        UIBarButtonItem *setButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"set" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(DatePickerDoneClick)];
        UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancelRepetition)];

        [controlToolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:spaser, setButton, cancelButton,nil] animated:NO];

        [mySheet addSubview:controlToolBar];
        [mySheet showInView:self.view];
        [mySheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 485)];

        return NO;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return myArray.count;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
   return [myArray objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if (chosen == reminderString) {
        reminderString =[myArray objectAtIndex:row];
        [reminder setText:reminderString];
    }
    else if (chosen == repetitionString){
        reminderString =[myArray objectAtIndex:row];
        [repetition setText:reminderString];
    }
}

- (void)DatePickerDoneClick{
    [mySheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}

-(void)cancelRepetition{
    [mySheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: you can give the name to pickers and then distinguish between them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can give the name to pickers and then distinguish between them for 
ex Picker1 and picker2 and in didselectrow put the condition

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

  if(pickerview == picker1)
{
 reminderString =[myArray objectAtIndex:row];
        [reminder setText:reminderString];
}

elseif(pickerview == picker2)
{

   reminderString =[myArray objectAtIndex:row];
        [repetition setText:reminderString];
}
```